# Axon Framework: send command on aggregate load

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, axon

We're building a microservices system with Axon Framework 4.1. In our domain, we have a label concept where we can attach labels to other entities. While labels are normally created and managed by the user, some of these labels are "special" and need to be hard-coded, but they need to be present in the event stream as well.

We have a bunch of aggregates that represent entities that can be labeled with these labels. Some of these aggregates will be used frequently, while others might be used infrequently or are even abandoned by the user.

Sometimes we come up with new special labels. We add them to the code, and then we also need to add them to the event stream. What is a good way to do that?

We can create a special command that we need to send when the updated service is started for the first time. It goes through all the labels and adds the ones that aren't in the event stream yet. This has two disadvantages. First, we need to actually send that command, which either requires us to not forget it, or to add some infrastructure for it outside of the code (e.g., in our build pipeline). Also, other services could have booted up faster with the new labels and started sending commands before we fired our special command. The other disadvantage is that this command will target all aggregates, including the abandoned ones, which could be wasteful of resources and be confusing to end users who might see activity in a document they thought was abandoned.

Ideally, we would like to be able to send the command when Axon has just loaded the aggregate. That way we would be certain that the labels are only introduced in aggregates that are actually used. Also, we could wire this up in code and it wouldn't require us to add infrastructure outside of the application and/or remember to do it manually.

Unfortunately, this feature doesn't seem to exist in Axon (yet) .

Are there other (better) ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've got an idea which might help you out on this.

If I understand the use case correctly, the "Label" in your system, which user can introduce themselves but for which also a couple of hard-coded versions exist, is an Aggregate.
Based on that assumption, I suggest to be smart with the Aggregate Identifier you are using.

The sole thing that Axon expects from you, is that the Aggregate Identifier is (or can be made in to) a `String`. Typically a `UUID` is used for the Aggregate Identifiers, which is a reasonable first start.
You can however wrap this `UUID` in a typed-id object. Taking your "Label" Aggregate, that would opt for a `LabelId`.

That said, let's first go back to verifying whether a given "Label" Aggregate exists within the Event Stream.
The concern you have is rather valid I think; reading the *entire* Event Stream to figure out whether a given Aggregate instance exists is to big of a hassle.

However, the `EventStore` can be queried through two mechanism:

1. The Event Stream from a given point in time (e.g. what the `TrackingToken` mechanism does).
2. The Event Stream for a given Aggregate instance, based on the Aggregate Identifier.

It's the second option which is far more ideal in your scenario.
Just query the `EventStore` for a given "Label" Aggregate's Identifier. If you receive a non-empty Event Stream, you know it already exists.
Vice versa, if no Events are found, you are certain it's a new "Label" that needs to be introduced.

The crux here is in knowing the "Label's" Aggregate Identifier up front, which circles back to the `String` storage approach for the Aggregate Identifiers using a typed `LabelId`. What you could do, is deviate in the `LabelId` object between a custom "Label" (I'd opt for a `UUID` here) and a hard-coded "Label".
For the latter, you could for example have the `label-name`, plus a `UUID`/counter if desired.

Doing so will ensure that all the Events published from a hard-coded "Label" will have an Aggregate Identifier you can anticipate on during start-up.

Hope this is clear and all, if not, please comment on my response below.

Comment: Querying the `EventStore` sounds like a good idea for a different problem. A little light: we have 1 Aggregate per document-instance which manages all the labels for that document. This Aggregate needs to emit additional events for newly added, hard-coded Labels. We could query the DB for all such management Aggregates and send them a Command, but we're looking and hoping for a better way :)

Comment: Ah bummer, so my answer pretty clearly does no resolve your problem, as it's an Aggregate Member we're talking about and not an Aggregate Root.

What you're suggesting at the end of your original question, some sort of hook in the Aggregate loading process, is however something I am unsure about should be added to the framework. My gut leans towards the fact not many people would use this (I could obviously be extremely wrong on this).

If you would be to build this yourself, I'd suggest wrapping the Aggregate `Repository` class in one way or another. What do you think @jhkuperus?

Comment: I could give that a try and see how big of an impact it is. We could explore the concept in my fork of the framework and have some discussion about it. For now we're going with checking a version just before executing certain CommandHandlers and emit events prior to handling the actual command.